# Homotopy pullback of a homotopy pushout is a homotopy pushout

Tags: ct.category-theory, gn.general-topology, homotopy-theory

Let's assume that we have a cube of spaces such that everything commutes up to homotopy.
The following holds:
    - The right square is a homotopy pushout and
    - all the squares in the middle are homotopy pullbacks.
I was told that (in Top) the left square is also a homotopy pushout then.
Do you know any source where this is stated? (Or: is this actually true?)

Answer (score 17):

This is Mather's second cube theorem, see Theorem 25 in

*Mather, Michael*, [**Pull-backs in homotopy theory**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4153/CJM-1976-029-0), Can. J. Math. 28, 225-263 (1976). [ZBL0351.55005](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0351.55005).